# Accessing storage of a map of a map

Tags: ethers.js, typescript, get-storage-at

I would like to access the storage of a specific contract using `ethers.js` and `getStorageAt`, but I can't get my head around how to do this for the `mapping(address => mapping(address => address))` type. I am experimenting with the `UniswapV2Factory.sol` contract of Uniswap available here (https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Factory.sol).

Here are the lines that matter:

```
contract UniswapV2Factory is IUniswapV2Factory {
    address public feeTo;
    address public feeToSetter;

    mapping(address => mapping(address => address)) public getPair;
    // ...
}
```

---

Based on the `getPair` type definition, how could I iterate through the values stored, and find existing pairs? Here's some sample JavaScript code - I would like to iterate through `getPair` in a similar fashion:

```
const contract = await new ethers.getContractAt("UniswapV2Factory", "0x...");

const token0 = "0x...";

for (const token1 of Object.keys(contract.getPair[token0])) {
  console.log("token0", token0);
  console.log("token1", token1);
  console.log("pair", contract.getPair[token0][token1]);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To do it that way, you must know what to look for, meaning that you should know beforehand some combinations of tokens addresses to compute the pair address for. Or, as @longhuynh suggested, you could rely on a service that does this dynamically for you.

First, you should read the [mappings storage layout](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays) definition, especially the part / example on nested mappings.

> The value corresponding to a mapping key k is located at
> keccak256(h(k) . p) where . is concatenation and h is a function that
> is applied to the key depending on its type.

In your example, `p` is `2` (encoded on 32 bytes) because `getPair` is declared at storage slot 2. To get the first level of the mapping you need to compute :

```
keccak256(abi.encode(token0, uint256(2))
```

Now to get to the second level, you need to reapply the same construction by considering the previous output as the storage slot of the inner mapping:

```
keccak256(abi.encode(token1) . uint256(keccak256(abi.encode(token0, uint256(2))))
```

Turning this into ethers.js :

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");

const ENDPOINT = "THE-ENDPOINT-URL";
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "THE-CONTRACT-ADDRESS";
const TOKEN0 = "THE-ADDRESS-OF-TOKEN0";
const TOKEN1 = "THE-ADDRESS-OF-TOKEN1";
const MAPPING_SLOT = ethers.BigNumber.from(2);

async function getPair() {
  const provider = await new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(ENDPOINT);
  const abiCoder = new ethers.utils.AbiCoder();

  // ABI Encode the first level of the mapping
  // abi.encode(address(TOKEN0), uint256(MAPPING_SLOT))
  // The keccak256 of this value will be the "slot" of the inner mapping
  const firstLevelEncoded = abiCoder.encode(
    ["address", "uint256"],
    [TOKEN0, MAPPING_SLOT]
  );

  // ABI Encode the second level of the mapping
  // abi.encode(address(TOKEN1))
  const secondLevelEncoded = abiCoder.encode(["address"], [TOKEN1]);

  // Compute the storage slot of getPair[token0][token1]
  // keccak256(abi.encode(address(TOKEN1)) . abi.encode(address(TOKEN0), uint256(MAPPING_SLOT)))
  const slot = ethers.utils.keccak256(
    ethers.utils.concat([
      secondLevelEncoded,
      ethers.utils.keccak256(firstLevelEncoded),
    ])
  );

  console.log(await provider.getStorageAt(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, slot));
}

getPair();
```

Feel free to modify the logic a little, so that you can pass the relevant values as parameters and simply iterate over the known token addresses that you want to check the pair for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to iterate through the value of a mapping, unless you store an array of keys for that mapping. Smart contract's storage layout for dynamic mapping is quite complicated (you can take a look at the [solidity's document](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays) for more details).

For a solution, perhaps you should consider using [The Graph](https://thegraph.com/en/)? It basically "listens" to the smartcontract's events, and store it in a structured database, so you can fetch that data and iterate easily.